# hiding a video and muting the sound

Tags: video, embed, hide, mute

I'm trying to hide an embedded video using som simple jQuery and it all worked fine till  turned my speakers on. The video hides fine but the sound keeps on playing in the background.

Is there a function I can cal that either mutes the video aswell or completely removes it?

Check the link below for an example, play the video then click the hide video link to see what I'm talking about. Been at this for ages and it's properly annoying me now.

http://jsfiddle.net/P3zKc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Vimeo's API reference is horrible, but check out this page. http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api Mainly the `play()` and `pause()` functions. It says you need to send any of these API functions indirectly to the iFrame containing the video. To do this you need to add `api=1` to the iFrame url like this `<iframe id="video2" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/16965687?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&api=1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"></iframe>` 
You can't call these functions directly on the iFrame though, you have to use `postMessage()` to send the function call to the iFrame.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage has some good documentation on the syntax of that function. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I've been looking into this but you're right the documentation is horrible.

I've managed to mute the video using `.remove();`. Since I was hiding the video anyway and didn't need to call it back this works ok.

Still the Vimeo API could be a useful thing to learn for the future

Comment: @Sam Hi Im having the problem of not being able to mute the audio, how did you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what video player you are using. I know [youtube](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#player_apis) has their own API.
Would be able to give you more info but your fiddle doesn't want to load for me. Maybe make another if someone else has this issue, and I'd be glad to help.

Comment: It's a vimeo video, I've updated the fiddle link see if this works any better. It still loads fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/P3zKc/1/